# NSTimer Not Invalidating

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have an NSTimer called "timer" and I am attempting to invalidate it when an int "milliseconds" reaches 217. I have tweaked the 217 to other numbers and it works. Just not on 217. Milliseconds starts at 5000 so it is always going to go past 217.

Code:

```
if (milliseconds == 217) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self explosion];
        bomb.hidden = YES;
        button.enabled = NO;
        NSURL *musicFile2;
        musicFile2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Explosion" ofType:@"wav"]];
        audioPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile2 error:nil];
        audioPlayer2.volume = 1;
        [audioPlayer2 play];
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like it will work if you change *milliseconds* to 218?

Answer (score 4):

With timers, always test for greater than or less than.  Testing for exact equivalency assumes the timer fires "exactly" when you need it.  Due to hardware or software timer resolutions or other things happening on the system, that may not occur.